# Как писать адаптеры на Kotlin. Android

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, kotlin

Как написать на `Kotlin` адаптер под андроид для `RecyclerView`. Как вынести `view` в переменную. Знаю, что есть прямой доступ, но нужно именно в переменную
`findViewById()` в котлине же не используется, как я понял

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var city:TextView = name_city as TextView
        var latitude_:TextView = latitude as TextView
        var longitude_:TextView = longitude as TextView
    }
```

Comment: Кто вам такое сказал про `findViewById()`? Используйте на здоровье.

Comment: вы можете использовать, **как альтернативу** импорт пространства имен виджетов (смотрите ["kotlin android extension"](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)), что намного удобнее (и тогда будет понятен первый ответ), но и классический вариант с findViewById() никто не отменял.

Answer (score 2):

Нет необходимости использовать `findViewById`

Обращайтесь к элементам интерфейса через `itemView` в `onBindViewHolder`.

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TeamViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val test = items[position] 
        holder.itemView.tv_name.text = test.name

  }
```

Если у Вас много `view`-элементов в `LAYOUT`-е адаптера, можете использовать `with` в том же `onBindViewHolder`.

```
             with(holder.itemView){
               tv_name.text = test.name
               tv_second_name.text=test.secondName
             }
```

Comment: Интересно как вы это представляете? `itemView` это просто `View`, а не `ViewDataBinding`. Разве у `View` есть объект `tv_name` ?

Comment: ItemView является рутовой View в нашем viewHolder.  Почитайте про kotlin extensions. Ваш ответ написан исключительно в java-стиле.

Comment: P.S. Другими словами — можно не  findViewById везде (Activity/Fragment/Adapter), используя Kotlin Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация переменных в `Kotlin` произойдет при вызове конструктора.
Так что можно сделать подобным образом:

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var city:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city)
    var latitude_:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latitude)
    var longitude_:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.longitude)
}
```